# ABT term reference field hidden in Node View

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am using "Access by Term" configuration to control VIEW and UPDATE access for a content type with a Term Reference field in the content type. See screenshot.

But setting this configuration hides the term ref field in Node View.

How do I fix this?

screenshot of the term ref ABT config fieldset:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to assign "Allow users to view ABT terms on node page." permission to desired roles.

Comment: Had completely forgotten about permissions page! Thanks for the answer